# Python power law trendline

Tags: python, regression

I'm looking to emulate the 'Power' trendline from Excel in Python, in order to fit a straight best fit line on an xy log-log scatter plot.

There are a few discussions/options on how to achieve this , however they are all overly sophisticated for what I'm after (eg. github.com/keflavich/plfit) or require knowledge of the mathematics that is beyond my ability.

I am aware that it isn't good practise to use something you don't fully understand, however this is just for a visual comparison.

Is there a quick/simple way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick/simple answer: use the appropriate formula to compute the parameters of the power law. You can find it here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPowerLaw.html